# Al porcionar cadenas en plsql y convertirlas con TO_NUMBER, aparece el error ORA-06502

Tags: oracle, plsql

Tengo un pequeño bloque plsql el cual busca en una cadena con delimitadores, extraer un dato en específico y almacenarlo en una variable. Este es el código:

```
DECLARE
P_PEDIDO VARCHAR(150);
V_MONTO_OPERACION NUMBER(10,2);
BEGIN
P_PEDIDO := '000003265478#01#01#000001654897#GS#0000300000.00#   0000COMPRA BIGGIE SAN. BER.B01#00000#000#000000000000';
V_MONTO_OPERACION := TO_NUMBER(LTRIM(SUBSTR(P_PEDIDO, INSTR(P_PEDIDO, '#', 1, 5)+1, INSTR(P_PEDIDO, '#', 1, 6)-INSTR(P_PEDIDO, '#', 1, 5)-1)),0);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_MONTO_OPERACION);
END;
```

La porción de cadena que se devolvería debería ser '0000300000.00', que es la sección de la cadena entre el quinto y sexto delimitador '#' en *P_PEDIDO*. Este valor se asigna a *V_MONTO_OPERACION* después de aplicar la función `TO_NUMBER` y `LTRIM`. No logro encontrar lo que está fallando; este es el error que obtengo:

```
DECLARE
*
ERROR en lÝnea 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: error  numÚrico o de valor
ORA-06512: en lÝnea 6
```

Comment: Antes de sugerirte una respuesta (porque tu `SUBSTR` + `INSTR`) está bien: en tu base de datos, ¿tu separador de decimales es el punto o la coma?

Comment: Otro tema, ¿estás queriendo hacer un `LTRIM` con ceros? ¿O le pasaste un cero a `TO_NUMBER`? (Me refiero al `,0` al final de la asignación de _V_MONTO_OPERACION_).

Answer (score 2):

Como mencionaba, dentro de todo *no está tan mal* lo que hizo OP, salvo el `,0` al final de la asignación de *V_MONTO_OPERACION*. Simplemente removiéndolo, ya debería funcionar:

```sql
DECLARE
P_PEDIDO VARCHAR(150);
V_MONTO_OPERACION NUMBER(10,2);
BEGIN
P_PEDIDO := '000003265478#01#01#000001654897#GS#0000300000.00#   0000COMPRA BIGGIE SAN. BER.B01#00000#000#000000000000';
V_MONTO_OPERACION := TO_NUMBER(LTRIM(SUBSTR(P_PEDIDO, INSTR(P_PEDIDO, '#', 1, 5)+1, INSTR(P_PEDIDO, '#', 1, 6)-INSTR(P_PEDIDO, '#', 1, 5)-1)));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_MONTO_OPERACION);
END;
```

Ahora bien, si al ejecutarlo aparece el error `ORA-06502`, probablemente sea porque en la base de datos el separador de miles es el punto, y el de decimales, la coma (asumiendo esto por la cadena de ejemplo que proporciona OP, donde se muestra que la moneda es *Gs* (*Guaraníes*)). Por lo tanto, al menos en este caso, se debe hacer un `REPLACE` de `.` por `,` antes de convertir el valor con `TO_NUMBER`:

```
DECLARE
P_PEDIDO VARCHAR(150);
V_MONTO_OPERACION NUMBER(10,2);
BEGIN
P_PEDIDO := '000003265478#01#01#000001654897#GS#0000300000.00#   0000COMPRA BIGGIE SAN. BER.B01#00000#000#000000000000';
V_MONTO_OPERACION := TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(LTRIM(SUBSTR(P_PEDIDO, INSTR(P_PEDIDO, '#', 1, 5)+1, INSTR(P_PEDIDO, '#', 1, 6)-INSTR(P_PEDIDO, '#', 1, 5)-1)), '.', ','));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_MONTO_OPERACION);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar con expresiones regulares;

```
DECLARE
    P_PEDIDO VARCHAR(150);
    V_MONTO_OPERACION NUMBER(10,2);
BEGIN
    P_PEDIDO := '000003265478#01#01#000001654897#GS#0000300000.00#   0000COMPRA BIGGIE SAN. BER.B01#00000#000#000000000000';
    -- V_MONTO_OPERACION := TO_NUMBER(LTRIM(SUBSTR(P_PEDIDO, INSTR(P_PEDIDO, '#', 1, 5)+1, INSTR(P_PEDIDO, '#', 1, 6)-INSTR(P_PEDIDO, '#', 1, 5)-1)),0);
    select to_number(regexp_substr (
           P_PEDIDO,
           '[^#]+',
           1,
           6
         ) ) value
         into V_MONTO_OPERACION
  from   dual;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_MONTO_OPERACION);
END;
```

El lugar que deseas obtener el es ultimo parametro de regexp_substr, creo que es 6 y no 5